# How to add a new build env variable (e.g. staging) in react-native?

Tags: xcode, react-native

I know in react-native we can use `__DEV__` to determine whether we are running the debug build or the release build.

I have created a new `staging` build config (for beta ver.) in Xcode and want to detect this env in js code as well. How can I do that?

The goal is to let my app connect to localhost api in `debug` build, to dev api in `staging` build and to production api in `release` build.

Comment: I want to achieve the same thing, anyone knows how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

With `react-native-config` you can add some 12 factor configuration to your mobile apps.
https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config

You can define your variables in differents files like `.env`, `.env.staging`, `.env.production`

There is support for JavaScript code, iOS and Android.